# Cython 1.1.2 and const correctness

Tags: python, cython, python-extensions

I am experimenting with Cython to write a python extension for my C library. I have created a setup.py file - but when I try to build my pxd and pyx files, I get an error.

After some investigation, it appears that Cython cannot grok functions with const parameters. Whenever I remove the const specifier, the compilation continues until the next function protype that has a const argument.

Is this a known limitation of Cython - or am I missing something more fundamental?

I am running Cython 0.11.2 with Python 2.6.5

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation, with workarounds documented in Cython's own documentation [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html?highlight=const).